# Treat json with unicode in csv column to replace with corresponding character

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, unicode

I have a csv file load into a pandas dataframe with 1 column like:

```
|Col1                 |  Col2                                                    
+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+                                                 
|rénovation thermique | ["consommation \u00e9nerg\u00e9tique de b\u00e2timents publics"] |
+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I treat this column to get the original character? I tried to loop thought every row and replace by hand the unicode but I can't anything in the data frame

```
df['Col2'] = df['Col2'].str.replace('\u00e2', 'â')
```

Comment: If it's actually JSON, you should `import json` and apply `json.loads` to every cell (using `DataFrame.apply()` or something – I don't know pandas). This will give you a list for each data point, so you might have to call `"".join()` on the list to get a string.

Comment: @lenz Thanks, the json.loads()  ","join() did the trick !